# How do I get char directly from keyboard not through buffer?

Tags: c++, c, input, keyboard, bgi

I am making a game which has a character moves in 4 directions: up, down, left, right corresponding to W,S,A,D on the keyboard. The problem is when using `getch()` to get input from buffer, it always has a pause time after the first single keypress. For instance, when I hold 'A' button, it acts like: `A(a short period of time)AAAAAAAAA`.

How do I get rid of that delay time?

Any help would be appreciated.

(Answers in either `C` or `C++` are all acceptable, since I am using graphics.h for this program, which requires `C++` to run, but I mainly code in `C`).

---

I am using windows 10 64 bits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448944/c-non-blocking-keyboard-input https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294713/non-blocking-i-o-in-c-windows

Comment: It depends on your unknown OS.

Comment: If what you really want is "key up/key down" events, then you should look at something like SDL (https://www.libsdl.org/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-Blocking i/o in c? (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294713/non-blocking-i-o-in-c-windows)

Comment: @irowe I tried the solution in that topic but it act like: when a key is pressed, then the character keeps moving until it hits the wall, in that time, I still can change the direction.

Answer (score 1):

### For a non-blocking getch method I personally use this piece of code (in C):

```c
#include <conio.h>

int getch_noblock(){
   return _kbhit() ? _getch() : -1;
}
```

the `_kbhit()` method returns 0 if no key are pressed, otherwise returns a number if the keyboard input buffer is not empty.

the `_getch()` method read a char from the keyboard buffer.

It works only for Windows.

### Documentation:

1. `_khbit()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-170
2. `_getch()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170

By the way, surfing on the web I found an interesting method, but I've never tried or seen it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-nolock-getwch-nolock?view=msvc-170

Comment: I have tried to use `getch_noblock()` instead of `getch()` but the program crash when I hit the first button. Do I need to re-config anything?

Comment: @Becker sorry for the stupid question, but did you include the conio.h library?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to rebuild several times but doesn't work

Comment: Mh.. I can suggest you to flush the standard input keyboard buffer (stdin) with `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: I tried it, but it still crash. The rolling circle of the mouse cursor start rolling immediately when the program run

Comment: @Becker could I see the complete code if not a problem?

Comment: The complete code is pretty long for a fast review. But I only call this "key handling" function one time in a while loop. And I think the functions contain underscore prefix does not work on my machine. (Sorry for late repply).

Comment: @Becker I don't know what you could try, I'm sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

getch() already bypasses buffer:

```
 Prototype
         int _getch(void);  

 Description
         _getch obtains a character  from stdin. Input is unbuffered, and this
         routine  will  return as  soon as  a character is  available  without 
         waiting for a carriage return. The character is not echoed to stdout.
         _getch bypasses the normal buffering done by getchar and getc.
```

And for your problem, as someone already said, you can use the `kbhit()` method